# LibGDX: How to make something like vector rotation sensor with accelerometer and compass values?

Tags: android, libgdx, rotation, vector, accelerometer

So I've tried the vector rotation sensor using the Android API and it works perfectly to do what I want, but LibGDX does not support this sensor. I've been searching and it seems like I can do the same thing as vector rotation sensor using the accelerometer and compass values returned by LibGDX API:

```
Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ();

Gdx.input.getAzimuth();
Gdx.input.getPitch();
Gdx.input.getRoll();
```

But I couldn't find out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rotation matrix by calling `Gdx.input.getRotation(float[] matrix)`, it gives you the rotation matrix as per the Android `SensorManager` `getRotationMatrix` call ([SensorManager.getRotationMatrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix(float[],%20float[],%20float[],%20float[]))).

From that you can get a `Quaternion` out that is a direction and a rotation around that direction.

So if you you're looking to get the *pitch*, *roll* and *yaw* you can retrieve those from the `Quaternion` directly;

```
    public class MyAndroidStudioSandboxGame extends Game {

        @Override
        public void create () {
        }

        @Override
        public void render () {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            float[] mat = new float[4 * 4];
            Gdx.input.getRotationMatrix(mat);

            Matrix4 m = new Matrix4(mat);

            Quaternion q = m.getRotation(new Quaternion());

            Gdx.app.log("SANDBOX", String.format(
                "Pitch=%.2f, Roll=%.2f, Yaw=%.2f", 
                q.getPitch(), q.getRoll(), q.getYaw()));
        }
    }
```

The above app will log the orientation ([Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)) of the device to logcat.
There are also `getPitchRad`, `getRollRad` and `getYawRad` that gives you the values in radians.

Comment: How can I use the returned values to get the rotation of the device in the three axes?

Comment: @AlexPi I added a code sample to show how to get the angles out. Hope this helps.